# Threading issues with animation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, animation

So, I know it's bad practice to ever sleep the UI thread. I've got an issue here though and I'm confused how to get around it. I have a loop that executes inside of the UI thread. One of the methods (`placeTile()`) has an animation associated with it. Because It's a loop, I need to pause code execution to give time for the animation to complete and allow the user to see what just happened. (Example, like dealing or drawing cards. They should see each tile placed one at a time so that they can follow the flow of the board game.)
But, since the Android API MUST be run on the UI thread, (Meaning the animation can't happen on a worker thread), how am I supposed to achieve this? If I pause the UI thread, the animation won't run, right? But I can't run the animation on a worker thread. And since the for loop includes the animation, does this mean I just can't pause the loop and allow the animation to complete?

I'm still pretty new to threading so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

Here's the code:

```
public void setUpPlayers(){

    //Toast for setting turn order
    smallToast(getResources().getString(R.string.deciding_turn_order));

    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if(i == 0){
            players[i] = new Player("HUMAN", 6000);
            players[i].setType(Player.Type.HUMAN);
        } else {
            players[i] = new Player(playerNames[i], 6000);
            players[i].setType(Player.Type.COMPUTER);
        }           
        players[i].drawTile(1);

        TextView nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_player_text);
        nameText.setText(players[i].getName());

        //find the ID for the tile just placed
        String tileID = players[i].findTileIdByIndex(0);

        placeTile(tileID, i); //Tile ID being placed, and the index of the player placing it

        //TODO: Pause and wait for animation to complete
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I know it's bad practice to ever sleep the UI thread`.

Correct, it's a **very bad practice** and you should avoid it as possible. You can easily achieve that by running a `Thread` that process what you're supposed to run within the main UI and then just update the main UI by declaring a `Handler`.

The steps are, you declare a `Handler` within your main UI, you access your `Handler` inside the `Thread` loop inside your class, and whenever you need to update something in the main `UI`, simply send a `Message` to the UI `Thread`.

```
static class MyHandler extends Handler {
  @Override
  synchronized public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
    final String myMessage = msg.toString();
    // Do whatever you need to do...
    ...
  }
}

final MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();

final Thread lowp = new Thread(
  new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
      // Do whatever you need to do
      ...

      // And call this when you have to do something in the main UI
      final Message mess = new Message();
      mess.obj = "Update the UI!";
      handler.sendMessage(mess);
    }
  });

myLoop.start();
```

Comment: I couldn't get your method to work because of scope issues across multiple classes. It did put me on the right path. In the end, I used `i` in the `for loop` to count how many seconds to add to the post delay by running everything inside of the loop in a new thread. That way, each iteration waits an extra 2 seconds for every previous iteration that already occurred.